# Why does this extension method not initialize the returned object?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I wrote a generic Extension helper method to initialize some parameters of a SoapHeader, however it is not updating the returned object.

What am I missing?

```
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

    public class Header: SoapHeader {}

    public class WS {
      public Header securityHeader {
        get;
        set;
      }

    }
    public static class SecurityHeaderExtensions {

      public static T GetSecurityHeader < T > (this T header, string actor, string role) where T: SoapHeader, new() {

        T result = new T() {
          Actor = actor, Role = role
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Actor: " + actor); //prints actor
        Console.WriteLine("Actor: " + result.Actor); //prints blank
        return result;

      }
    }

    void Main() {
      var ws = new WS();
      ws.securityHeader = ws.securityHeader.GetSecurityHeader("actor", null);

    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you expected and what happened?

Comment: What is the type of `ws.securityHeader`?

Comment: Looks like the property setter for `Actor` is throwing away the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `Actor` and `Role` are the same field internally.

Setting it to `actor` then setting it to null means that it's `null`.

> The recipient of that data, known as the SOAP **Role** in version 1.2 of the SOAP specification and the SOAP **Actor** in version 1.1

Comment: Good sleuthing. That wasn't obvious at all.